# NodeJS won't return data to jQuery.getJSON

Tags: jquery, node.js, getjson

I've set up NodeJS and it's returning data when I browse to the URL: http://184.106.206.235

However, when I try to call that URL using `$.getJSON`, the callback shows `null` for the `data` variable and `"success"` for the `textStatus` variable.

I imagine this could be a cross-domain thing, but I'm surprised that the `textStatus` says `"success"` if that's the case.

In case it's helpful, here's the server-side JS:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var output = {message: "Hello World!"};
  var body = JSON.stringify(output);

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': body.length});
  res.end(body);
}).listen(80, "184.106.206.235");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the JavaScript hosted on `http://184.106.206.235`?

Comment: Yes, though I'm trying to access it using "client" JS hosted on a different domain.

Comment: Well that'd be your problem then. What "text status"?

Comment: If you look at the callback for http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/, you'll see that it's supposed to return "data" and "textStatus" objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" property to your writeHead() call:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
});
```

Comment: The content type for json data should be application/json, see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Answer (score 3):

Just a note for anyone having the same problem, the solution above worked for me with one minor alteration:

"Content-Type": "application/json"

Not "text/json".

Thanks for the solution! It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using [express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.json%28%29) framework you can try one of the following:
1. `res.contentType('json');` to set to content type.
2. `res.send({ some: 'json' });` that will set the content type and parse it for you.
3. `res.json({ user: 'tj' });` probably the best way to do it.

hope it helps :)