# unable to read json file via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my code i have:

```
   $.ajax({
       url: 'http://chapters.zmgc.net',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(d){   // "Type","Name","Link","Contact","Location","Icon"
        Tabzilla.zgContacts = d;
        var countries = [];
        d.rows.forEach(function(row){
          if (row[0] == 'Country') countries.push(
            {link:row[2], contact:row[3], country: row[4]}
          );     
        });
```

but i get an error, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
....
```

if i replace the url with the actual file and remove the dataType, all works as expected!

i have validated the output of http://chapters.zmgc.net at http://jsonlint.com/ and it is ok.

looking at the response headers returned from http://chapters.zmgc.net, it is:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 13 Dec 2012 17:02:27 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

here is the code https://github.com/tomarcafe/Z-Tabzilla/blob/gh-pages/z-tabzilla.js#L282 i would like to replace the local file with reading the remote data?

what am i missing?

Comment: Can you put your json here?

Comment: try `dataType: 'json'` instead of `jsonp`.

Comment: You are accessing a third party URL. This is subject to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You cannot access the data unless the server supports a way to do so or you use your own proxy.

Comment: Adding `jsonp` doesn't magically make it cross domain.  The server needs to support JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're asking for JSONP (JSON with padding) and getting JSON without padding. JSONP is JSON that is padded by a function call, and the only way to get it to work is by adding support for JSONP on the server.

If you don't have access to `chapters.zmgc.net` you'll have to contact them and ask them to add support for JSONP.

If you do have access you can add `?callback=parseThis` to your url and then read that variable on server-side and pad your JSON accordingly:

```
parseThis(/* put your json in here */);
```

However, if you don't define your own callback, jQuery will add one automatically that you can use. They will look something like this: `jQuery18200710562220774591_1355419375476`

Comment: i get the same error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :' when i change the code to

`$.getJSON("http://chapters.zmgc.net?callback=?", function(json) {
     // ... rest of the code
     console.log(json);
   });`

Comment: @khinester That's because `chapters.zmgc.net` is not returning JSONP but just normal JSON. I've explained this in my answer.

Comment: ok i have fixed this now with the help from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3602574/477340 and did not have to change my code!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set type to `jsonp`, That is JSON with padding, in that it is assumed that response is wrapped inside a function call.

`callback({payload: values});`

and will tried to be executed.

Instead use type: json, or simply `$.getJSON` which will correctly pass the JSON payload with `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: I am guessing he is using `jsonp` to make it work cross-domain. If so, this won´t do it for him.

Comment: I think it still works, jQuery will create a new function and pass it as the callback function name, ultimately it comes down to the same thing. (Never tried this though, I stand to be corrected!)

Comment: jQuery only creates a callback function if you tell it it's a JSONP request, otherwise it will treat it as a normal JSON request.

Comment: no, I think if he can change the url to be in format 'http://chapters.zmgc.net?callback=?' it should work with $.getJSON (Assuming server knows to wrap the JSON in the callback. again, I did not try this)

Answer (score 0):

As Ajax uses jsonp (json with padding) but your url doesn't seem to be jsonp compatible, so you have to avoid using that.

from jQuery:

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra
>   "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables
>   caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the
>   URL unless the cache option is set to true.

more here : http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/